# Using SharedPreferences with different Contexts

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-context

I want to use SharedPreferences between multiple activities and the idea is that I'll have one class that access the SharedPreferences and returns it to different activities via static methods. My question is: since SharedPreferences needs a context to be initialized and I'll be giving it different contexts from different activities will the values still be accessible?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: instead of using Activity Context use `getApplicationContext()` for creating or sharing `SharedPreferences` in whole Application

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `Context` provided to `.getSharedPreferences()` is only there to let the system access your application-specific information; every `Activity` in your app shares the same preferences.

Comment: Do you mean that every Activity shares the same Context?

Comment: Every activity has its own context, but the information in shared prefs remains the same for your entire app, regardless which context you access it from (as long as its a context from your app).

Comment: @RaghavSood Ah ok, thanks for the help. I'll accept your answer as soon as it allows me to :)

Comment: @SweSnow It isn't my answer :P I was just helping out. Eric's the answering user :P